# Perform 4d FFT and specify frequency domain

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, fft

I encountered this problem while researching on image reconstruction of two-slab geometry. Suppose I have an array of 15 by 15 sources with spacing 1 on one plane, with an array of 57 by 57 detectors with spacing 0.5 on the other parallel plane. The total measurement data becomes hence a 4-d array of size 57 by 57 by 15 by 15. My first thing to do is to perform a 4-d (or more accurately double 2-d) Fourier transform to the data with respect to the detector lattice and source lattice respectively, and I want to use the built-in function `fft2` in MATLAB. My code is as follows:

```
for s = 1:Ns
    data(:,:,s) = fftshift(fft2(data(:,:,s)));  % fft2 assumes exp(-i*omega*t)
end

data = reshape(data(:,:,1:Ns),[Nx,Ny,sqrt(Ns),sqrt(Ns)]);

for i = 1:Nx
    for j = 1:Ny
        data(i,j,:,:) = fftshift(fft2(squeeze(data(i,j,:,:))));
    end
end
val = data;
```

In the above code, `data` is the measurement and is originally of size 57 by 57 by 225. `Nx`=`Ny`=57,`Ns`=225. Can anyone point out to me whether there is something going wrong in my above implementation of double 2-d FFT, or at least how I am able to verify it? My second question is about the frequency domain. According to doumentations of MATLAB, the frequency lattice with respect to detector plane should be `(-28:28)*2*pi/57/0.5` (for both components), while the frequency lattice with respect to the source lattice should be `(-7:7)*2*pi/15/1` (for both components also). Is that true? Can one say that the element at position (29,29,8,8) of `val` represents exactly the 0 frequency both for the detector frequency and for the source frequency? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you applying `fftshift` before taking the second `fft2`?

Comment: @Suever I was considering shifting the zero frequency to the center of the matrix before performing the second `fft2`. Does that make sense, or did i actually make a mistake here?